# Octave puts file read by dlmread to console

Tags: octave

myFile.asc is a large point cloud with million of points (rows) in the form of

```
  -13.204000000   30.858300000   15.898300000
  -13.204300000   30.864600000   15.899400000
  -13.195000000   30.857300000   15.901000000
```

```
P = dlmread('/myPath/myFile.asc', " ")
```

stores the pointcloud successfully in **P** but unfortunately gives each line to console out in Octave. How can I suppress the logging here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a semicolon at the end to suppress the output:

```matlab
P = dlmread('/myPath/myFile.asc', ' ');
```